# Cannot Resolve Symbol Android Studio v1.2

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and have just started to create a "Hello World!" type program with a piece of text and a simple button. However, when I go to Run "app", around 160 errors come up saying Cannot Resolve Symbol. I haven't changed anything in the build file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material"/>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1"/>
```

The android part is labelled in red.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Build | Clean Project
```

For Hello World you can simply go through

```
File | New | New Project | Next | Next | BlancActivity | Finish
```

Then you can run your app in a debug mode. You can also compare source files of your two HelloWorld's and find out why there is an error.